# Не работает cron на CentOS 6.8 из директории /var/spool/cron

Tags: centos, cron, crontab, centos6

Привет всем, столкнулся с проблемой, когда крон **из директории**

```
/var/spool/cron
```

**не запускается**, то что находится в файле просто для него не существует, логи пустые несмотря на запущенный сервис крона.

Задания работают если их вписать напрямую в файл /etc/crontab в таком виде:

```
*/1 * * * * root /yandex.disk/Backups/script.sh
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: судя по стилю описания ситуации, велика вероятность, что вы не знаете о существовании как программы *crontab* вообще, так и её опции `-e` в частности, и о том, чем пользовательские crontab-ы отличаются от общесистемных.

Comment: сделайте `crontab -l` из-под нужного пользователя и дополните свой вопрос выводом этой команды

Comment: Вот что у меня получилось
`*/2 * * * *  /yandex.disk/Backups/script.sh >> /yandex.disk/test.log >/dev/null`